# My object disappears is not hidden

Tags: objects

My object is not hidden but in any case I can not see the object，The object will appear when rendering But I did not hide to the object
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide blend-file?

Comment: 我的文件下載檔案 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9AIC7MxieHpQ3V5aWljVmdRTmc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - It is a [clipping tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html) in blender.

All that you need to do ― it's just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> second time