# My eevee render engine shows results like this for any scene though my cycles engine can render how it's supposed to

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

this is how my Eevee renders scene there is a lamp and a cube in the centre of the frame yet it shows nothing every time.

Comment: please show us your blend file so we can help

Comment: Are your drivers up to date ?

Comment: Looks like your cube is just very big. Can you add another object, or show a solid view screenshot?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84422/my-object-disappears-is-not-hidden/84425#84425